# Object modelling using openCV GMM class

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mixture-model

**BACKDROP**:
In openCV video processing, I have segmented foreground as **n** number of blobs.

**Question**:
OpenCV 2.3 provides a class called GMM.
How can I model a blob's pixels using a GMM. I am new to Gaussian mixture modelling. I can undestand its functions but i am not sure of the sequence of execution.

**source**
http://opencv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3.1-0exp1/classGMM-members.html
http://opencv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3.1-0/modules_2imgproc_2src_2grabcut_8cpp_source.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial on OpenCV segmentation using graph cuts and gaussian mixture models here: http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/05/05/bust-out-your-own-graphcut-based-image-segmentation-with-opencv-w-code/